# JavaFX - Bad font rendering - color fringes - blurry tex

Tags: fonts, javafx

Using LTS 20.04 the font rendering of JavaFX applications is very bad.

[image: image of color fringing on letters]

I'm asking this question so I can answer it myself. It took me some hours of search and trial and error to find the solution. Maybe next one finds it faster here.

Answer (score 0):

Solutions are:

1. Install openjfx12
2. Install libfreetype6-dev if openjfx12 not available
3. Or just create the missing link `sudo ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfreetype.so.6.17.1 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfreetype.so`

The result:

[image]